# calculating half-edges/faces of arbitrarily generated lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this [script](http://jsdo.it/mrdoob/xI3u) by mrdoob that generates a web of lines. I've figured out where a line begins and where it ends. Now I want to extrude faces from these shapes, however all I have are lines and vertices. I'm trying to read through some half-edges theory, but i don't think I understand it that well.

Is it a matter of following a line until it's a rectangle, checking if it intersects a line or subdivides? I need a bump in the right direction.

```
// Based on Jared Tarbell's Substrate algorithm concept.
// http://www.complexification.net/gallery/machines/substrate/index.php

var Boid = function ( x, y, angle ) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.angle = Math.pow( Math.random(), 20 ) + angle;
    this.dx = Math.cos( this.angle );
    this.dy = Math.sin( this.angle );

    this.life = Math.random() * 100 + 100;
    this.dead = false;

    this.update = function () {

        context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo( this.x, this.y );

        this.x += this.dx * 2;
        this.y += this.dy * 2;
        this.life -= 2;

        context.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
        context.stroke();

        var index = ( Math.floor( this.x ) + width * Math.floor( this.y ) ) * 4;

        if ( this.life <= 0 ) this.kill();
        if ( data[ index + 3 ] > 0 ) this.kill();

        if ( this.x < 0 || this.x > width ) this.kill();                        
        if ( this.y < 0 || this.y > height ) this.kill();

    }

    this.kill = function () {

        boids.splice( boids.indexOf( this ), 1 );
        this.dead = true;

    }

}

var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var canvas = document.getElementById( 'world' );
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
var image, data;

var boids = [];
boids.push( new Boid( width / 2, height / 2, Math.random() * 360 * Math.PI / 180 ) );

setInterval( function () {

    image = context.getImageData( 0, 0, width, height );
    data = image.data;

    for ( var i = 0; i < boids.length; i ++ ) {

        var boid = boids[ i ];
        boid.update();

        if ( !boid.dead && Math.random() > 0.5 && boids.length < 500 ) {

            boids.push( new Boid( boid.x, boid.y, ( Math.random() > 0.5 ? 90 : - 90 ) * Math.PI / 180 + boid.angle ) );

        }

    }

}, 1000 / 60 );
```

Comment: Your question looks interesting :) but I need more information, so I can help you (or know if I can). What do you mean with "extrude faces" and "these shapes"; are "these shapes" the polygonal areas you are drawing? and by "extrude faces" you mean to draw a "2D representation of a 3D _building_"? (emulating what you can do in _blender_ or _3DStudio_)

Comment: Ok. So the script dynamically draws lines which intersect each other. What I want to do is ascertain the 4 points that form a shape reflected by the lines on the canvas. As of right now, the points are independent and in no way "connected." I haven't had much experience with three.js, but I believe you need the vertices to create edges.

Comment: About this algorithm: If your are going to use this algorithm you should add a *termination condition*; you can change the initialization of the interval to `var myIntervalId = setInterval(theFunctionHere)` and after the _for loop_ add `if(boids.length==0){clearInterval(myIntervalId)}`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more complicated than I tough. I'm not sure if it is the answer you are asking for, but may help you to decide the next step:

If you have to use this algorithm: I think you are going to need to keep track of every pair of points that makes an edge: the first point at the beginning of the `Boid` function and the second when the `Boid` is killed; both points (or the x1, x2, y1 and y2 values) are saved in a new `edge` object that will be added to an `edges` array (every `edge` will be kind of the soul of a death `Boid`).

There are two problems before applying the [half-edges theory](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/half-edge-based-mesh-representations-theory/): you have an array of edges, but you need to know what other edges are connected to the beginning or end of a given edge. The other problem is that the "collision" between two Boids only affects the Boid currently being updated, which is killed during the collision. In order to use the half-edge theory you'll have to "notify" the other Boid/edge about this collision and split it at that point: a collision point is a vertex of three edges, the one that collides and the two in which the one being collided was split.

Also note that the shapes (faces) are not necessarily made of four edges, I opened the link you provider and there where a lot of shapes with tree and five edges.

If you can use a different algorithm for generating the mesh then you may have a better representation of the edges and vertexes that will help you to find the "corners" that makes every shape.

Comment: thanks. Yea when one boid collides with another is what I need to figure out. When it collides I know the x,y, so then it's a matter of figuring out which boid it collided with. I would have to loop through every single boid to check to see if that x,y lies on a particular boid. Is that really bad for performance? Is there a better way other than going through every line, every collision?

Comment: Yes, it'll be really bad for performance for the number of boids being generated by that script unless you can reduce the size of the canvas or the number of boids: my screen is 1920x1080 and the drawing slows down as the number of boids increase.

Comment: I can't think of a better solution, but there must be a better one. If you are going to test every line already drawn (the Edges array) you can add to the Edge a field that holds the slop(gradient) of the line and a function which calculates that slop (once, and save it) and then determines if a given point (the collision point) lies on the line using the line equation. It would be better to find another algorithm that gives you a better representation of the edges and nodes in order to make easier this part.